# How to estimate probabilities of different classes for a Text

Tags: nlp, text-mining, probability

Suppose I have a piece of writing and I want to assign probabilities to different genres (classes) based on its contents. For example

> Text #1 : Comedy 10%, Drama 50%, Fiction 20%, Romance 1%, Mythology 5%, Adventure 10%
>
> Text #2 : Comedy 40%, Drama 3%, Fiction 2%, Romance 30%, Mythology 5%, Adventure 10%

We have given keywords possibly ngrams in each class through which we make a comparison

> Class 1 Comedy : k11, k12, ..., k1m
>
> Class 2 Drama : k21, k22, ..., k2n
>
> Class 3 Fiction : k31, k32, ..., k3o
>
> Class 4 Romance : k41, k42, ..., k4p
>
> Class 5 Mythology : k51, k52, ..., k5q
>
> Class 6 Adventure: k61, k62, ..., k6r

What can be the best probabilistic model that we can use for this task

Comment: Is your list of genre keyword associations the only training data you have? Do you have a set of texts that are labelled with the correct genres?

Comment: @Imran  No Data is pretty less here, we only have a list of n-gram keywords per genre. More keyword match should result in higher probability and less keyword should result in lesser probability per genre.

Comment: Can a text have multiple genres? In other words, is it OK if the assigned probabilities add up to more than 1?

Comment: @Imran I can easily use Naive Bayes here by considering each genre as a different class but it will distribute the probability across multiple classes. What I want is to assign probability individually i.e. per class.

Comment: So this would be a valid prediction: Comedy 90%, Drama 10%, Fiction 70% ... ?

Comment: Also, how can you use Naive Bayes without any training data? How do you compute the prior and the likelihood?

Comment: We have given keywords as mentioned above for training and we predict probability of a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, we are interested in soft [multilabel classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification), where a single text can have multiple correct genres.

According to your comment, we don't have any training data, just a list of keywords associated with each genre.

We can try computing the similarity between each document and each keyword list:

1. [Normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_normalization) the document (convert to lowercase, remove punctuation, diacritics, non-alphanums, etc)
2. Remove [stopwords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words)
3. Convert the document to [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) vector over our genre keyword vocabulary: Each document gets an n-length vector where each entry is the frequency of the ith genre keyword in the document. Normalize this vector to magnitude 1.
4. Convert each genre keyword list to a tf-idf vector in the same way (again over the keyword vocabulary for all genres).
5. Compute the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) between the document vector and each genre vector.

For each document, this will give us a number in the range [0,1] for each genre. For example:

```
         Comedy Drama Fiction Romance Mythology Adventure
Text #1: 0.15   0.11  0.03    0.00    0.00      0.07
```

If we were doing single label classification we could normalize each row to add up to 1 and we might have a working model. However there is no such trick for multilabel classification here. We don't have a good way to calibrate these values into probability estimates.

At this point the only solution I see is to build a small training set so we can fit our model to actual data.

After gathering some training examples, we can run a multilabel regression with [sigmoid activation and binary crossentropy loss](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/234578/1104) with the cosine similarities as input features to get a probability estimate for each class.

Using this method our list of genre keywords will at least save us having to build a large training set to solve the problem directly with [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) or similar approaches.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, I understand what you are trying to say. Can we modify Naive Bayes for multi-label classification.

Comment: Could you update your question to describe how you are calculating prior and likelihood for Naive Bayes? Then I can try and help you extend it to multi-label classification

Comment: Training Naive Bayes simply by considering each genre as a different class. I read some articles they mentioned that `Naive Bayes` won't give better results for this task (i.e. `Multilabel Classification`). I think I should stick with your approach.

Comment: Yes you could train seperate 1-vs-all Naive Bayes classifiers for each class, but you still need a training set. Just having a list of keywords does not tell you about the prior distribution of classes nor the probability of a class given a piece of text. For both of these you need to fit to labelled training data. Naive Bayes isn't magic!

Comment: Hello @Imran Is there a need to down-weight term frequency of keywords. `TF-IDF` is widely used for text classification but here our task is multi label Classification as you mentioned i.e to assign probabilities to different labels. I believe creating a `TF` vector by `CountVectorizer()` would work fine because here we are concerned more with presence or absence of keyword in a document rather than how important is it as compared to other documents. What do you think ?

Comment: I think TF is fine because you have already identified important keywords and you're creating the vector over that vocabulary. I almost said TF only in my answer but I wasn't totally sure so I went with the standard approach.